# Hibernate ignore entity field while reading and use for persisting

Tags: hibernate

I have requirement where i need to ignore entity field for reading data (select) and when the same entity i used for persistence (insert) for other data-source ignored field should be used. please help me out for the same.

Comment: can you able to post what you have tried?

Comment: Following field are need to be ignore for reading and same need to use for persistence, @Column(name="SCHEMA",columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String SCHEMA;@Column(name="PROCESSORNAME",columnDefinition="TEXT") private String PROCESSORNAME;, since i am using single entity object for different data-source for reading and writing.

Comment: did you tried  `@Transient` annotation?

Comment: I have tried with @Transient it will ignore from both read and write

Comment: selective columns  also will work  for example `select e.name,e.dept,e.mark1 from studentmarklist`

Comment: which is mapped to your entity will assign remaining fields will be null